# Metodo Jquery dentro de ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

el proble que tengo es que este metodo jquery que esta dentro del ajax  `$(this).parent().parent("tr").remove();` no funciona y creo que es por que no reconoce la funcion this, si lo coloco arriba funciona perfectamente pero la idea es que funcione despues del success del ajax

```
$("#tablaproducto").on('click','.eliminar','.productotemp',function(e) {

    ideliminar =$(this).siblings("#ideliminar").val();

             var datos = new FormData();

            datos.append("ideliminar",ideliminar );


            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                url:"factura/eliminar",
                type: "POST",
                data: datos,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(respuesta){

                var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);

                    if(obj.idproducto>= 0){

                     $(this).parent().parent("tr").remove();

                    }else{

                    alert('Error al ELiminar');


                    }
    }
        });


    });
```

aqui dejo el html

```
 <tbody style="background-color: white;" id="tablaproducto">
     @if($total==0)

            @else
   @foreach($valor as $key=>$productos)

        <tr>

            <th>{{$productos["nombre"]}}</th>
            <th>$ {{ number_format($productos["precio"], 0) }}</th>
            <th>{{$productos["cantidad"]}}</th>
            <th>$ {{ number_format($productos["total"], 0) }}</th>
            <th><img src="/imagenes/agregar.png"></th>
             <th><img id="eliminar" src="/imagenes/eliminar.png"><input type="number" id="ideliminar" value="{{$productos["idproducto"]}}" hidden></th>
        </tr>

        @endforeach
         @endif


  </tbody>
```

Comment: a que elemento te estas refiriendo cuando colocas `this` ?

Comment: $("#tablaproducto") a este el funciona solo que no dentro del ajax

Comment: probaste agegando `$("#tablaproducto")` en vez del `this`?

Comment: Si es lo que supongo, `e` hace referencia al objeto [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event). Podrías usar: [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target), en vez de `this`. Saludos

Comment: si agrego de esa manera funciona el problema es que al hacerlo asi borra el elemento aleatorio de la tabla y de la forma en que lo coloco borra justamente el elemento que le indico

Comment: @MauricioContreras me puedes ilustrar como ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de la función success `this` cambia de contexto.

Al inicio del callback de click guarda en una variable el valor de `this`

```
let $this = $(this);    
let ideliminar = $this.siblings("#ideliminar").val();
```

De esa forma, puedes utilizarla dentro del callback o de cualquier función interna sin que pierda su contexto

```
success: function(respuesta){

    var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);

        if(obj.idproducto>= 0){

         $this.parent().parent("tr").remove();

        } else{

        alert('Error al ELiminar');


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema muy probablemente se puede resolver utilizando funciones flecha.

Intenta definir tu función de la siguiente manera:

```js
$("$tablaproducto").on("click", ".eliminar", ".productotemp", function(e) {
  // Tu contenido aquí
  
  $.ajax({
    // tus datos para la conexión,
    success: (respuesta) => {
      // Aquí la función que necesitas
    }
  });
});
```

Inténtalo y espero te funcione.